# How to show numpad on mobile without using input type number/tel?

Tags: javascript, html

How to show numpad on mobile without using input type number/tel?

I have looked into this, but can't seem to find anything. I have an input that I cannot make into a number input because of some validations I'm doing. I was wondering how to show a numpad without using the `input` type `number`/`tel`?

Comment: If you'll only accept numbers for the field's value, what kind of validation requires it to be text type?

Comment: I have some credit card validation that auto formats with spaces and underscores

Comment: Read [`this`](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html) article. It's out of date, but gives you some direction.

Comment: Try `type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"`, see https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/type-number.html

Comment: Of course you'd need to add space and _ to the pattern, not sure it'd still pop up the numpad then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal world, the this is exactly what the [`inputmode`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#input-modalities%3A-the-inputmode-attribute) attribute would let you do.

> User agents can support the inputmode attribute on form controls (such
>   as the value of textarea elements), or in elements in an editing host
>   (e.g., using contenteditable).
>
> The inputmode content attribute is an enumerated attribute that
>   specifies what kind of input mechanism would be most helpful for users
>   entering content.

You would use it like this:

```
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric">
```

However, as of right now, [it has limited support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode) only being available in some of the most recent versions of Chrome and Chrome for mobile.

Comment: so would this be something like `<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" />` ?

Comment: @TaylorAustin yes